# Typing numbers on a MacBook Pro with AZERTY keyboard with Caps Lock — possible?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, capslock, shift

I have a Belgian AZERTY keyboard on my MacBook Pro. Sadly, it appears to be impossible to use `Caps Lock` to type numbers — I still need to hold `Shift` for every number I want to type. Is it possible to change the `Caps Lock` key’s function to `Shift Lock` so that it affects the whole keyboard rather than just the letters? I’d like to be able to type numbers without holding `Shift`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In System Preferences, Keyboard set your keyboard to *French Numerical*, et voilà ;)

(You might need to change it once again in the menu bar on the top right.)

Comment: Wow, just like that huh? Thanks!